# How to find popular search from a set of search strings in php?

Tags: php

I have a data set of searches made on a website. I have to find top searches from that data set. The problem is, i cannot think of a way to do it. The search terms are long sentences. How could i find what are users interested in? It seems to be a problem of counting and i am using php. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make counter corresponding to each phrase. Suppose You have a queries in long sentence format , divide your sentence into smaller parts and identify the most meaningful word and avoid the conjuctions and other verbs. Particularly focus on Nouns. For an eg, Query is : How to Make account on stackoverflow? Possible Solutions[words] : account, stackoverflow,make. Possibly in this way you can solve it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a table in database, which will contain columns `search_phrase` and `counter`. Each time when user will search same phrase, you'll just increase counter instead of creating new row.
You can also create a script which will take all records from this table, and find similar phrases.